# find the specific part of string between special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

i am trying to find specific part of the string using regex or something like that.
for example:

```
string = "hi i am *hadi* and i have &18& year old"
name = regex.find("query")
age = regex.find("query")
print(name,age)
```

result:

```
hadi 18
```

i need the 'hadi' and '18'

> Attention: The string is different each time. I need the sentence or
> words betwee  ** and &&

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? What happened when you tried putting `python regex tutorial` into a search engine?

Comment: about the regex tutorial you are right. but about the question. well i searched and i didnt find the answer.

Comment: You are supposed to think about the examples you are given, think about the rule that tells you what to look for in the string, think about the tools described in the tutorial, and then write the code. Just as you would for *any other programming task*. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users .

Comment: ok dude im just gonna delete my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import re

string = "hi i am *hadi* and i have &18& year old"

pattern = r'(?:\*|&)(\w+)(?:\*|&)'

print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

**Outputs:**

```
['hadi', '18']
```

You could assign `re.findall(pattern, string)` to a variable and have a Python list and access the values etc.

**Regex demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/vIg7lU/1

The `\w+` in the regex can be changed to `.*?` if there is more than numbers and letters.  Example: `(?:\*|&)(.*?)(?:\*|&)` and demo: https://regex101.com/r/RIqLuI/1

Comment: You could shorten the alternation to a character class `[&*](\w+)[&*]` but note that this could also possibly match `*18&`

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved my question:

```
import re

string = "hello. my name is *hadi* and i am ^18^ years old."

name = re.findall(r"\*(.+)\*", string)
age = re.findall(r"\^(.+)\^", string)

print(name[0], age[0])
```

Comment: Quick to answer your own question.  So you didn't really have a question in the first place then?

Comment: believe me or not but i really did not know how to do that. just used some creativity and regex101 :))

Comment: That's a good solution, and you've learned more than if you'd gotten the same answer from someone else, congratulations :-) And it happens to veteran users too: Writing the question sometimes helps you figure out the solution on your own.

Comment: thanks fow your support. at least someone understand me

Comment: its better to use `re.search` instead of `re.findall`. no more dealing with result as a list